# Is it OK to truncate log tables?

Tags: db-logging

I've got detailed logging turned on, and everything is getting stored in a separate DB, but it's getting pretty big. Is it OK simply to truncate the tables? Clearly I'll lose the data, and the ability to roll back changes, but I need to keep the size of the database under some sort of control.
If so, how could I delete everything older than say, the last 3 months? [This post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28920/is-there-a-process-to-tidy-the-tables-created-by-logging) offers some clues on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can delete/truncate the log tables. It's not used for anything except the change log / manual investigations.

That post you linked to answers your second question: `DELETE FROM log_civicrm_XXX WHERE log_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)`